# Rails: accessing models from utility classes, and from other threads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model called `Workflow` and an action called `execute` defined on it. A `Workflow` has many `Step`s.

Each time I execute a `Workflow`, I want an instance of another model called `Job` to be created. Additionally, some kind of a background job will go through the list of `Step`s in the `Workflow` and run them.

Currently, I create and save an instance of `Job` in the `Workflow#execute` action. But the background job of executing the successive steps will be defined in some class placed under `app/classes`. It will likely run in a separate thread.

I want to represent the the running instance of each `Step` in the context of a `Job` as a model - call it `Task`. I need to create instances of `Task`s from this background job.

1. Can I access the model classes from arbitrary classes under app/classes.
2. Will adding `Task` objects from a different thread be thread-safe?
3. Are there better / recommended patterns for handling such scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you can, provided the Rails environment is loaded within the process that attempts that.
2. Without specific precautions it will not be thread-safe. There are many ways to ensure thread safety, the simplest one being not using class variables for tracking state and using explicit transactions around database operations. To be absolutely certain, you can wrap your thread-sensitive operations in mutex lock.
3. Yes, using a background jobs solution instead of raw threads for handling the tasks. There are Resque, Sideqik and Rails' own DelayedJob for starters. Those provide means of managing the tasks, handling errors, scheduling and such. If you choose to go this way it's likely you won't need a dedicated `Task` model as its role would be carried out by an actual background job class.